# Jquery mobile site 'mini' on Samsung Galaxy Note

Tags: jquery-mobile

My issue is with the collapsible block 'accordion' menu. I initially followed a tutorial online and it was only when I got to applying the collapsible blocks that I realised the tutorial was quite old and the scripts I had copied from the tutorial were:

with these scripts, the collapsible content simply cannot be set to be closed by default so data-collapsed="true simply doesn't work and the menus are open by default. After much googling it seems other people has the same issue and when upgrading to the latest script version the problem was sorted so when I updated to the current up to date versions i.e.:

The data-collapsed="true did work however every page now goes tiny on the screen. Please see the below screenshots to see what I mean.

What is wrong here, is it a css issue?

> Using the older scripts I had this: http://www.magnetikmedia.co.uk/m/old_script.png

[image]

> Using the newer scripts I had this: http://www.magnetikmedia.co.uk/m/new_script.png

[image]

I know the Galaxy note has a massive screen but using a mobile site emulator (to see sites on various handsets) the site looks fine on there (although now and again this morning when browsing the site on an emulator of an iphone 5 for example, the screen shrinks as per my screenshot so there must be a bug somewhere) The code from the head to the end of one page is here as the other pages are the same just with different content

```
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mobile.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>


<!-- Start of first page -->
<div data-role="page" id="home">

<div data-role="header1">
<div align="center"><img src="http://www.magnetikmedia.co.uk/m/images/magnetikmedia_header.png" width="90%"></div>
</div>
<div>
<div align="center"><img src="http://www.magnetikmedia.co.uk/m/images/welcome_banner.png" width="100%"></div>
</div><!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content">   
    <ul data-role="listview">
<li data-role="list-divider"><h3 align="center">Digital Design & Development</h3></li>

<li><a href="#about">
<div class="mobile_menu_hpage"></div>
  <div class="list-text">About Us</div>
</a></li>

<li><a href="#getsocial">
  <div class="mobile_menu_hpag"></div>
  <div class="list-text">Get Social</div>
</a></li>

<li><a href="#services">
  <div class="mobile_menu_hpag"></div>
  <div class="list-text">Services</div>
</a></li>

<li><a href="http://www.magnetikmedia.co.uk/portfolio.htm">
  <div class="mobile_menu_hpag"></div>
  <div class="list-text">Portfolio</div>
</a></li>

   <li><a href="http://www.magnetikmedia.co.uk/contact.htm">
  <div class="mobile_menu_hpag"></div>
  <div class="list-text">Contact Us</div>
</a></li>
</ul>   
</div><!-- /content -->

  <div id="footer1">
<div id="footer_left">
<div align="center"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/magnetikmedia"><img src="http://www.magnetikmedia.co.uk/m/images/fbook_foot.png" width="30" height="30" style="margin-right:10px;" ></a><a href="http://www.twitter.com/magnetikmedia"><img src="http://www.magnetikmedia.co.uk/m/images/twitter_foot.png" width="30" height="30" style="margin-right:10px;" ></a><a href="http://magnetikmedia.blogspot.co.uk"><img src="http://www.magnetikmedia.co.uk/m/images/blogger_foot.png" width="30" height="30" style="margin-right:10px;" ></a><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/magnetikmedia"><img src="http://www.magnetikmedia.co.uk/m/images/linkedin_foot.png" width="113" height="30" style="margin-right:10px;" ></a></div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
</div>
  <div align="center"><!-- /footer -->

  </div>
</div><!-- /page -->
```

Comment: I think the best way of explaining this is the content and the footer have just shrunk. On my galaxy note 2 the header images are full size and fine but everything else (content and footer) has shrunk so the footer is halfway up the page as you can see. Even if i set the footer to position: fixed it goes to the bottom of the screen but is still tiny (the icons I am using have shrunk within the footer) Incidentally, both screen shots are from my phone so it can't be the large screen size.

Comment: If the issue is with `data-collapse=true` remove it an use this code to collapse menu. `$('[data-role=collapsible]').collapsible();`.

Comment: It's not just the collapsible menu it seems, I have completely removed the 2 pages that use that menu so no collapsible menu anywhere but same issue still. The other issue with links not working is back now too!

Comment: After much testing I have pinpointed the issue to the versions of jquery I am using. If i use much older versions of the css and query i.e. jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js and code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a1 my display is fine (as per the first image attachment) As soon as I change to the current versions I get the 'mini site'. How am i to pinpoint exactly what it is that is causing the issue?

Comment: If you make a completely new page, without copy/paste old markup, do you encounter the same?

Comment: if i use the latest .js and style sheets from here http://jquerymobile.com/download and use a boilertemplate from the site here http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/pages/docs-pages.html yes, I get the miniature header, footer and text. This is using exactly as the template says, without me adding anything to it. The only thing I added is the head section like this `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>`

Comment: Thing is if you look on an emulator like this one http://www.mobilephoneemulator.com it displays ok most of the time on those handsets! (although it wasn't earlier) and still same on my phone. I've filtered it right down to just the one page until I sort this but if you want to look the address is www.magnetikmedia.co.uk/m/indexbest.html

Comment: Is it down to something in my head section? (I know there are 2 <head> tags, ignore that, just a typo from me.

Comment: Do you have this in the head? `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: It wasn't but I just added it, no luck still.

Comment: Have you tested the page on another mobile/platform?

Comment: Tested on Galaxy Note (android 4.1.1_ Galaxy mini (android 4.1.2) and iphone 5. Same on all.

Comment: I added this viewport and it is sorted! <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width"> I did use Omar's viewport code but mustn't have refreshed it properly. It seems that with older versions of JQM, you don't need this code.

Comment: Haha, finally! I'll add this as an answer.

Comment: Thanks Omar, you've been a real help and I've learnt a bit along the way :)

Comment: Welcome :) pls mark the below as an answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `viewport` meta tag as follows.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```